# Calculate $\int\limits_{-1}^1\int\limits_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^1\int\limits_{-1}^1(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}\,dz\,dx\,dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

How to integrate this using cylindrical coordinates:

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^1\int_{-1}^1(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}\,dz\,dx\,dy$$

Now what I can understand is that we can directly integrate the $z$ part. Now I am confused in transferring the $x$ part from $(x,y,z)$ to $(r,\theta,z)$ as here $\theta$ will vary from $0$ to $2\pi$ but what about the $r$ part?

Please help.

Comment: You know that in cylindrical coordinates, $x^2+y^2 = r^2$, right?

Comment: yes, if the $x$ co-ordinate will vary from $-\sqrt{1-y^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ then the resulting change would be $-1$ to $1$. But I can't get here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUY7sOf7MrU

Comment: see this, $r$ is taken from $-2$ to $2$ in the integration we can take $r$ negative.

Comment: $\frac{1}{5} \left(7 \sqrt{2}+2 \pi +3 \sinh ^{-1}(1)\right)$